# How to get Real path of the app in the play

Tags: playframework

like this in servlet use:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
  throws ServletException, IOException {  
    String  filePath = config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");  
}
```

How to getRealPath in the play ?

Answer (score 5):

Play is all about being easy, right ? so let's keep it simple:

I use
    [Play.applicationPath](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.1.1/index.html) which returns a `File`.

Note that there are a few other cool path in the Play class:

- frameworkPath
- javaPath
- templatePath

Answer (score 3):

```
VirtualFile path = play.vfs.VirtualFile.fromRelativePath("/");
```

This will give you the path. From the returned object, you can get the File object, get the path as a String using `getName()` and do normal file type checks, like `exists()` and`isDirectory()` etc.

Take a look at the javadoc for more info.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.1/play/vfs/VirtualFile.html

Comment: From Play 2.x the API changes and the method ``fromRelativePath`` doesn't exist any more (at least in Java API).

Answer (score 0):

You can use also : `Play.getFile(".")` this method return a object File

See javadoc : [http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.1/play/Play.html#getFile(java.lang.String)](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/1.1/play/Play.html#getFile%28java.lang.String%29)

Answer (score 0):

In Play 2.0 (scala) try this:

```
import play.api.Play.current
val playPath = current.path.getAbsolutePath
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java Play 2.x project, do this: `play.Play.application().getFile(".")`.